# How to align table content in Android

Tags: android

I want to align content of TableLayout in android.
I want align the table headers too. what changes needed in main.xml?

```
<TableRow android:layout_margin="0dp" android:id="@+id/myRow"> 
<TextView android:id="@+id/myTitle" android:layout_span="5" android:text="" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</TableRow> 
<TableRow> <TextView android:layout_span="5" android:background="#000000" android:height="1dp" android:gravity="right" /> 
 </TableRow>
```

[image]

Comment: Please show your xml what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is not where you should show your xml, post it in you question itself in a proper format. Thanks.

Comment: i have uploaded my current table display in android. i want columns to be aligned to right.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Developer pages about Common Layout Objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#tablelayout). You have to add gravity to your elements inside your table.

Answer (score 1):

No problem since every table row has its own definition.

use the "gravity" to achieve your needs, for example

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="left"></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"></TextView>
</TableRow>
```

- the textbox in the first column is left-alligned
- the textbox in the second column is centered vertically and horizontally

which turns out to look like this:
[image]

have a look here for [gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html) details

additionally you can use padding to preserve some space left/right/above/under

Comment: the `android:layout_weight="1"` thing also might be essential